# How to show only permitted user_type fields on frontend

Tags: filter, wordpress, frontend, usertype

How would one go about creating a function/plugin for the following?

I have two user_types, FREE and PAID.

Both users have certain fields they can fill in. The PAID user has more fields they can fill in.

If a PAID user reverts back to a FREE user, how can only the FREE fields show on the frontend without showing the already PAID fields?

There must be a way to filter the fields per user_type? I'm very much a noob at writing code.

If anyone could explain and guide me, that would be great.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this some time ago for something different. It was about showing content only to users with a specific user level.

You could [register new user roles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) and check whether the current user (of the site, probably logged in) has the appropiate user role to view specific content.

I used `is_user_in_role` on the frontend and that works fine for me.

Concerning the PAID fields: Let the users fill them with content but add a notice like "Pay to show these fields publicly" on the frontend when he visits his own profile (or whatever you are building). This sometimes works very well for getting more paid users (make sure, you really have a benefit from those fields).